# Pyspark - filter, groupby, aggregate for different combinations of columns and functions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by

I have a simple operation to do in `Pyspark` but I need to run the operation with many different parameters. It is just filter on one column, then groupby a different column, and aggregate on a third column. In `Python`, the function is:

```
def filter_gby_reduce(df, filter_col = None, filter_value = None):
  return df.filter(col(filter_col) == filter_value).groupby('ID').agg(max('Value'))
```

Let's say the different configurations are

```
func_params = spark.createDataFrame([('Day', 'Monday'), ('Month', 'January')], ['feature', 'filter_value'])
```

I could of course just run the functions one by one:

```
filter_gby_reduce(df, filter_col = 'Day', filter_value = 'Monday')
filter_gby_reduce(df, filter_col = 'Month', filter_value = 'January')
```

But my actual collection of parameters is much larger. Lastly, I also need to `union` all of the function results together into one dataframe. So is there a way in spark to write this more succinctly and in a way that will fully take advantage of parallelization?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by generating the desired values as columns using `when` and `max` and passing these to `agg`. As you want the values unioned you have to unpivot the result using `stack` (no DataFrame API for that, so a `selectExpr` is used). Depending on your dataset you might get `null` if a filter excludes all data, these can be dropped if needed.

I'd recommend testing this vs the 'naive' approach of simply unioning a large amount of filtered dataframes.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
func_params = [('Day', 'Monday'), ('Month', 'January')]

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('Monday', 'June', 1, 5), 
    ('Monday', 'January', 1, 2), 
    ('Monday', 'June', 1, 5),
    ('Monday', 'June', 2, 10)], 
    ['Day', 'Month', 'ID', 'Value'])


cols = []
for column, flt in func_params:
    name = f'{column}_{flt}'
    val = f.when(f.col(column) == flt, f.col('Value')).otherwise(None)
    cols.append(f.max(val).alias(name))

stack = f"stack({len(cols)}," + ','.join(f"'{column}_{flt}', {column}_{flt}" for column, flt in func_params) + ')'

(df
    .groupby('ID')
    .agg(*cols)
    .selectExpr('ID', stack)
    .withColumnRenamed('col0', 'param')
    .withColumnRenamed('col1', 'Value')
    .show()
)

+---+-------------+-----+                                                       
| ID|        param|Value|
+---+-------------+-----+
|  1|   Day_Monday|    5|
|  1|Month_January|    2|
|  2|   Day_Monday|   10|
|  2|Month_January| null|
+---+-------------+-----+
```